# Is there a way for a wizard to gain cure spells on his spell list at first level?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, spells

Aside from the Samsaran Mystic Past Life racial trait is there any way for a first level wizard to gain cure spells as spells known at first level?

Answer (score 3):

### Nope.

After looking into adding spells to caster lists extensively when building a pathfinder character, I found a few methods to do so, but none that worked at level 1 other than Mystic Past Life.

To my knowledge, which is extensive if not absolute, there is no way to add spells to a list as a first level wizard beyond that ability.

There may be a way to do whatever it is you want cure spells *for*, but to gain specifically arcane cure spells at first level without just taking a level in one of the classes that gets arcane cure spells, the only way I know of is Mystic Past Life.

Comment: You missed Two-World Knowledge, but it doesn't apply to cure spells anyways (only level 0 spells can be added). And magic items of course.

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe so.

The [Life](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/core-classes/wizard/arcane-schools/paizo---arcane-schools/classic-arcane-schools/necromancy/life) subschool of [Necromancy](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/core-classes/wizard/arcane-schools/paizo---arcane-schools/classic-arcane-schools/necromancy) offers some healing abilities but not specifically the "Cure" spells. The Necromancy school overall focuses more on abilities affecting undead anyway.

I know the [White Mage](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/hybrid-classes/arcanist/archetypes/paizo---arcanist-archetypes/white-mage) [Arcanist](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/hybrid-classes/arcanist) archetype can, however.

If this is a pre-character-building question, the White Mage may be something to look at. If this is an in-campaign question, I fear you may be out of luck. Short of finding scrolls or a wand and having a good Use Magic Device skill bonus, I don't think there's a way to actually put the Cure spells on your spell list.