# What are the ways for a Wizard to get cure spells?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, spells, wizard, healing

Inspired by [this question](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/74227/is-there-a-way-for-a-wizard-to-gain-cure-spells-on-his-spell-list-at-first-level); I was intrigued to know ways at any level that a Wizard could cast *cure* spells, without using Use Magic Device.

Solutions should not use multiclassing and only use official pazio pathfinder books (No third party)

Ideally this should be "Cure" spells, but I'll take any way of curing hits that doesn't involve base Wizard spells such as "Infernal healing" (Due to the "evil" component), sorry.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The most common approach is to use Summon Monster spells to heal.  You can increase your options for this with the "Summon Good Monster" feat.  Here's a list from [reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/Pathfinder_RPG/comments/7cpj9j/summons_that_can_heal/); I've added an [SGM] tag to the options that require the feat:

> **Summon Monster III**:
>
> [SGM] Silvanshee Agatheon - Lay on Hands 1d6 1/day, at-will Stabilize
>
> **Summon Monster V**:
>
> Bralani Azata - Cure Serious Wounds 2/day
>
> [SGM] Vulpinal Agathion - Lay on Hands 3d6 6/day, Remove Disease, Calm Emotions Aura
>
> [SGM] Unicorn - Cure Light Wounds 3/day, Cure Moderate Wounds 1/day, Neutralize Poison 1/day
>
> **Summon Monster VI**:
>
> [SGM] Kirin - Lesser Restoration 7/day, Cure Light Wounds 8/day, Stabilize At Will
>
> Lillend Azata - Cure Serious Wounds 2/day, Cure Light Wounds 5/day, Bardic Performance as 7th-level bard
>
> **Summon Monster VII**:
>
> [SGM] Movanic Deva - Remove Curse, Disease, and Fear at will, Cure Serious Wounds 7/day
>
> [SGM] Shedu - Empowered Cure Moderate Wounds 3/day, Dispel Magic 3/day, Remove Disease 3/day, Shield Other 3/day, Restoration 1/day
>
> **Summon Monster VIII**:
>
> [SGM] Monadic Deva Angel - Dispel Magic at will, Remove Curse, Disease, Fear at will, Cure Serious Wounds 3/day, Heal 1/day
>
> [SGM] Lammasu - Cure Moderate Wounds or Lesser Restoration 7/day, Cure Light Wounds 7/day, stabilize at will
>
> **Summon Monster IX**:
>
> Astral Deva - Remove Curse, Disease, Fear at will, Dispel Magic at will, Cure Light Wounds 7/day, Heal 1/day
>
> [SGM] Couatl - Cure Moderate Wounds 7/day, Stabilize at will
>
> Azata Ghaele - Cure Light Wounds at will, Dispel Magic at will, Heal 1/day, Restoration 1/day, Cure Serious Wounds 3/day, Lesser Restoration 2/day, Stabilize at will
>
> [SGM] Leonal Agathion - Cure Critical Wounds 3/day, Neutralize Poison 3/day, Remove Disease 3/day, Heal 1/day
>
> Trumpet Archon - Mass Cure Serious Wounds 2/day, Heal 2/day, Mass Cure Light Wounds 1/day, Neutralize Poison 1/day, Cure Serious Wounds 1/day, Cure Moderate Wounds 2/day, Lesser Restoration 2/day, Cure Light Wounds 3/day, Stabilize at will.

There's also [limited wish](http://paizo.com/pathfinderRPG/prd/spells/limitedWish.html) and *wish* itself, which can duplicate cleric spells for you.

The [Samsaran](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/races/other-races/uncommon-races/arg-samsaran) trait "Mystic Past Life" allows you to add spells to your spell list.  The trait says: "The spells must be the same type (arcane or divine) as the spellcasting class you're adding them to", but I guess some people argue that (for example) *cure light wounds* can be an arcane spell since it's on the bard spell list.

You could use magic items such as a [gloves of first aid](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic-items/wondrous-items/wondrous-items/e-g/gloves-first-aid) or a [ring of spell storing](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic-items/rings/ring-of-spell-storing).  Each of these say in their description that they allow you to cast the spell yourself.

If you were playing in 3.5e you could take the [Arcane Disciple](http://alcyius.com/dndtools/feats/complete-divine--56/arcane-disciple--92/index.html) feat and add healing spells to your spell list.  That doesn't work in Pathfinder, though.

Comment: Samsarans have an alternate racial trait called Mystic Past Life that can add cure spells from the witch list to their spell list.

Comment: That's discussed in the question linked from this one, but you're right that it deserves mention here.  Am I right that, to get cure spells as a wizard, you have to convince your DM that cure is an arcane spell because it's on the bard spell list?

Comment: It's rules-vague, but bards cast arcane spells and bards cast cure spells, so cure spells can be arcane spells. (If you are okay paraphrasing the 0th Law of  Thermodynamics). Check with your GM, I guess.

Comment: Think this will be the closest I'll get, thanks for the answers!

Answer (score 1):

["Infernal Healing"](http://pathfinder.wikia.com/wiki/Infernal_healing) does that. I'm not sure about the more peculiar requirements though. There is also a [greater version](http://pathfinder.wikia.com/wiki/Greater_infernal_healing) available at level 4.

Both spells come from Paizo's [Gods and Magic](http://pathfinder.wikia.com/wiki/Gods_and_Magic) rulebook.

Comment: The question excludes *infernal healing*.

Comment: It didn't when I answered. That said, I fail to understand the question now. Any level wizard healing w/o magic devices w/o basic wizard spells? My limited understanding of the subject could be the issue here.

Comment: Yeah it could use a bit of work.

Comment: The objection to Infernal Healing is purely from a character point of view; they are "evil" spells. I'll clarify that :)

Comment: So you need cure spells for your non-evil wizard? That's more clear, thank you; but I'm still unable to help due to my lack of experience. Good luck in your search!

Answer (score 1):

The Arcane Physician Wizard Archetype (PPC:Healers Handbook) give you some access.
You treat healing spells on the Alchemist spell list as if they were on the Wizard list for the purpose of using or crafting magic items.

Also you get Brew Potion instead of Scribe Scroll.

So you can make healing potions and use wands of Cure Light, Moderate, etc. without needing to make UMD checks.

Likewise if you take Craft Wand you can make your own Wands of Cure Wounds.

Answer (score 0):

There are many many ways to heal in Pathfinder

Troll Styptic:
Not a spell but an alchemical item though still very similar to infernal healing, the problem is that it is a painful cure that can nauseate. Very handy to have around for whenever magic (even potions) are not an option (see woundweal)
http://www.archivesofnethys.com/EquipmentMiscDisplay.aspx?ItemName=Troll%20styptic

Vial of Efficacious Medicine:
A wondrous item and not too pricey at 700gp, along with its main use of boosting alchemical items every time you use it you are healed for 1d8+5 and you can do that 3x per day. You could load it with the cheapest alchemical remedy (Alchemist's Kindness, 1gp) each time. Still a bit awkward to load and drink repeatedly in combat.

Godless Healing: this is a Feat that lets you heal 1d8 + your hit die as a move action. There is a Trait called Accelerated Drinker that will let you drink a potion as a move action and that may be better if you can get Potions.

Shawl of Life Keeping: This is 1k Shoulder-slot wondrous item has upsides and downsides. The upside is it heals 10hp without requiring any action from you. The downside is that it only applies it when you get to 0hp or lower, so it's a handy safety net mainly.

Heal Skill: everyone has this, with the Treat Deadly Wounds option it's possible to heal up to 1hp+ the wis bonus of the healer. That means if someone with 14 Wis heals a wounded lv 1 player they are healed 3hp, but healing a level 3 player they recover 9hp. This takes an hour, it's no quick fix in combat.

Cleric in town with Level 4 spells: If you can find a high enough cleric NPC, get them to cast Imbue With Spell Ability on you, there is a standardized pricing for getting NPCs to cast spells on you listed here:

http://paizo.com/pathfinderRPG/prd/ultimateEquipment/gear/lodgingAndServices.html

This way you can get TWO casting of Cure Light Wounds (1d8+5) and ONE casting of Cure Moderate Wounds (2d8+7) and you cast them as if you were Cleric only much more forgiving mental stat requirements. No need to mess around with UMD. That means you can cast it on yourself or on an ally within touch. This is entirely dependent on your GM actually having such a character in your world, but can easily relieve the burden that you MUST have a cleric in the group.

Talisman of Healing Power: This thing is CRAZY expensive at 2400gp but when you lose only half your hit points you get healed by a massive amount for no action.

Note on Infernal Healing:
Infernal Healing is really very good, it heals 10hp for a CL1 scroll compared to only an average of 5.5hp for a Cleric stockpiling CL1 scrolls of Cure-Light-Wounds. *The text for Infernal Healing is absolutely unequivocal that it doesn't affect alignment*

> The target detects as an evil creature for the duration of the spell
>   and can sense the evil of the magic, though this has no long-term
>   effect on the target’s alignment.

It doesn't even make them appear evil, only that evil is about.

it is only nominally and superficially evil. No where does it say a good character cannot use this, no where does it say this is going against a character's alignment, alignment talks of actual effects and healing wounds can be an inherently good act regardless of contradictory auras.

Other things like Troll Oil, Fervour Juice and Wound Paste are related to taking large amounts of damage but don't actually heal you. You may do better doing more to avoid being hit, or taking down your foes quicker before they can hit you, but that's another question entirely. I'm just saying you should be careful trying to lean on healing too much.

Comment: This does not seem to answer how a caster could cast healing spells? Just lists a bunch of ways to heal, whether you are a caster or not.

Comment: I don't remember seeing that originally but the text for spell Infernal Healing is unequivocal it has no effect on actual alignment. And logically, how can healing wounds actually be evil? Though it does add "I'll take any way of curing hits" which includes non-spells and things non-specific to wizard.